# Yii2 join with active record

Tags: php, yii2

```
$slider = Slider::find() 
    ->joinWith([
        'slides' => function (ActiveQuery $query) {
            $query->addOrderBy(sprintf('%s.position', Slide::tableName()));
        }
    ], false)
    ->one();
/* OK */
SELECT "sliders".* 
FROM "sliders" 
LEFT JOIN "slider_slides" 
ON "sliders"."id" = "slider_slides"."slider_id" 
ORDER BY "slider_slides"."position"
```

The problem is that when I accees to relation `$slider->slides` debugger shows me additional query:

```
SELECT * FROM "slider_slides" WHERE "slider_id"=1
```

which does join useless.

Comment: Don't you know about   `eager loading `

Comment: Set the second parameter of `joinWith` to true (which is the default value). See [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail).

Comment: @Doubleh @robsch  `eager loading` makes few queries with `=` or `in` condition for relation.